# How to change Salesforce Sites Default behavior when user isn't logged in without setting up new domain

Tags: community, deployment, force.com-sites, login, custom-domain

I have a site. It's been deployed into the sandbox I'm working in and production via copado. I've not set up any domain for either. The site works almost perfectly. They have asked me to change from the default screen to a custom login though when a page requires login. I really don't want to start messing with the domain settings when everything else is working, but everything I've seen seems to indicate to me that I have to set up some kind of new domain to change these settings. Is this the case, or since I've already set them up should there be a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In the workspaces option on the All Sites screen. Click on administration there are options to manage the login screen for the sites.